# Setting Cookie not working in Spring web-mvc 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies

I need to set a cookie with redirect in my login controller. I used code below to set cookie.

```
@RequestMapping("/fbresponse")
public String getToken(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "code") String code, HttpServletResponse sResponse) {
    sResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("logged", "123"));
    return "redirect:"+user.getLastPage();
}
```

In my index I try to retrive the cookie using following code:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String getIndex(@CookieValue(value="logged", required=false)String test){
    user.setLastPage("/");
    loginCheck();
    System.out.println(test);
    return "index";
}
```

But it always returns null. I tried returning new ModelAndView. It also did not work and since I need some components in model it does not suit my requirement.
How can set and retrieve a cookie? Is it possible to do it with redirect?

**UPDATE**
I have class level @RequestMapping in my login controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

   @RequestMapping("/fbresponse")
   public String getToken(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "code") String code, HttpServletResponse sResponse) {
       sResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("logged", "123"));
       return "redirect:"+user.getLastPage();
   }
}
```

When I remove the class level request mapping add cookies works. How can I add a cookie correctly with class level request mapping?

Comment: You probably need to set the path of the cookie: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setPath%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: It corrected the issue. Can you please add this as a answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to [set the path](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setPath%28java.lang.String%29) of the cookie, otherwise it's valid only for the current path.